# iOS 13 disable floating keyboard feature for UITextFields

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, beta

We need to disable floating keyboard feature in our app, because it breaks all our keyboards in app((. I can't find any way to do this for UITextFields(property or something else).

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: no code, it is just working for every text field, but I am searching how to disable this feature.

Comment: I think that you should look at UITextInteractionDelegate (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinteractiondelegate)

Comment: It is not clear how to use this...

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a way to disable it or detect that it will be used. There also isn't a way to invoke it if you wanted to respond to a pinch gesture like the real keyboard does.

What has worked for me and my custom views is to use auto layout as much as possible.

When you need to change the look beyond auto layout you can override `willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?)` and then adjust based on the new smaller width. Size classes / traits won't work for trying to hide things as the floating digital keyboard shows up as a regular width and regular height instead of compact.